# having issue in select all check boxes at the time on file drop using angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

here what i am doing is i am creating a "Drag n Drop feature" using ng2 file upload and here my issue is when ever im trying to drop more than one file the select all function will be enabled and it will select all check boxes by default but that is not happening in my scenario after file drop

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r6cbrj

```
<div class="container"> 


<div class="well well-lg metadata-well text-center add-file ">

                        <h4  style="float:left ">
                        <span *ngIf="uploader?.queue?.length> 1">&nbsp;
                        <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" [(ngModel)]="selectAll" (change)="selectAllFiles($event)" class="form-check-input deltha">
                        </span>Add Files</h4>
                    <br />
                    <br />
</div>

<span *ngIf="uploader?.queue?.length== 0">
                        <p class="text-wrap">Your upload queue is empty.
                            <br />Drag and drop files to add them to the queue</p>
                    </span>





<span *ngIf="uploader?.queue?.length > 0">
                        <div class="upload-section">
                            <table class="table">

                                <tbody>
                                    <tr *ngFor="let item of uploader.queue;let i = index">
                                        <td style="padding-top: 0rem"> &nbsp;
                                          <div class="form-check">
                                              <label class="form-check-label">
                                              <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"  value="{{item?.file?.name}}"  [checked]="fileSelectState[item?.file?.name]"
                                              (change)="fileChecked($event)">
                                            </label>
                                          </div>
                                      </td>


                                        <td  id="{{ item?.file?.name }}">

                                            <a (click)="selectFile($event);">
                                                <strong>{{ item?.file?.name }}</strong>
                                            </a>

                                        </td>
                                        <td>{{ item?.file?.size/1024/1024 | number:'.2' }} MB</td>
                                        <td >{{ item?.file?.type}}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <button type="button" class="icon-button" (click)="item.remove();fileRemoved(item)">
                                              <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                                            </button>
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>

</span>
 <div ng2FileDrop [ngClass]="{'nv-file-over': hasBaseDropZoneOver}" (fileOver)="fileOverBase($event)" (onFileDrop)="fileDropped($event)" [uploader]="uploader" class="well well-sm metadata-well-sm text-center my-drop-zone">
                        <img  src={{imga}} />
                        <p>Drag and drop your files here</p>

                    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: you put checkbox inside `<span *ngIf="uploader?.queue?.length> 1">` which only becomes visible when you have 1+ files in queue.

Comment: @ABOS yes if i drop more that 1 file then it will be visible and if it is less than then only single checkbox

Comment: @Dexter, would you either please 'accept' an answer or explain what doesn't work for you.  TBH I was looking for the 50pts..  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in your StackBlitz:

See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rtzkhd

```
  constructor(){
    this.uploader.onAfterAddingAll = () => {
      this.selectedFilesArray = [];
      this.uploader.queue.forEach(fileItem => {
        this.fileSelectState[fileItem.file.name] = true;
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: And how do you uncheck all the files?

Comment: you would uncheck all by: `this.fileSelectState = {}` or one by one with `this.fileSelectState[fileItem.file.name] = false;`

Comment: could u update the stack blitz url again the above one is expired

Answer (score 2):

A solution (maybe not the best) :

```
public fileDropped(fileList: any): void
{
  for(var i =0 ; i< fileList.length; i++){
      this.fileSelectState[fileList[i].name] = true;
  }

}
```

You setting nothing in fileSelectState, which is bound to the **checked** attribute of your checkboxes.

This code adds the files names to **fileSelectState** as properties when files are dropped.

So to check or uncheck the boxes you can play with the values true/false of the **fileSelectState** properties.

---

Added this code to you selectAllFiles function :

```
for (var item in this.uploader.queue) {
  this.fileSelectState[this.uploader.queue[item].file.name] = e.target.checked
}
```

Here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-twlvwd

There are a lot of things that could be done better. You should consider refactor your code when you have time.

Comment: Could u able to apply it in my stack blitz

Answer (score 0):

You have done nothing to with `fileSelectState`. That is why your code is not working.
And also `selectAllFiles()` method work only when you change the value.

So what you have to do is write a function for input checked,

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"  value="{{item?.file?.name}}"  [checked]="checked(item)"
```

then you can give the logic that you want,

```
public checked(item:any):boolean{
  console.log(item)
  //relevant logic
  return true;
}
```

for now I just have returned true. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hshhge?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: i have functionality depended on it  [checked]="fileSelectState[item?.file?.name]" so that why i didn't removed it

Comment: @Dexter bro its a variable. so how can you say you have a functionality? and you have assigned nothing there? how can it work?

Comment: by using that variable only my web app have some internal functionalities like   if (this.fileSelectState[fileName] == undefined)
        this.fileSelectState[fileName] = '';
      for (var k in this.fileSelectState) {
        if (k !== fileName)
          this.fileSelectState[k] = false;
        else
          this.fileSelectState[k] = true;
      }
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(){
    this.uploader.onAfterAddingAll = () => {
      this.selectedFilesArray = [];
      this.uploader.queue.forEach(fileItem => {
        this.fileSelectState[fileItem.file.name] = true;
      });
    }
  }
```